# Como hacer forma de rombo con números en php?

Tags: laravel

Como puedo hacer este patron? tiene que ser un rombo con partes iguales arriba y abajo

Es el resultado de una funcion que recibe un parametro para construir el diamante

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora (la parte de arriba del rombo)

```
<?php

$n = 9;

for($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++)
   {
     /* print blank spaces */
     for($j=0;$j<=0-$i;$j++)
    printf(" ");

   for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++)
     printf($j);

    for($j=$i-1;$j>=$n;$j++)
     printf($j);
     printf("<br>");
   }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO en español, questions must to be written in spanish, otherwise they will be closed; also please read [ask], you need to show what you have at the moment and specify which doubts do you have

Comment: Hola Carlos, la pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: Ya la cambie Elena

Comment: como te mencionaba, aparte de mostrar el resultado final al que quieres llegar, deberás mostrar que has intentado o o investigado aclarando donde tienes dudas

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue

Comment: Falta saber qué falla en tu código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo tienes resuelto, la parte de abajo debes construirla al revés, quedaría así:

```
$n = 4;

echo"<center>";
for($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++) {
    /* print blank spaces */
    for($j=0;$j<=$n-$i;$j++)
        printf(" ");

    for($j=0;$j<=$i-1;$j---)
        printf($j);

    for($j=$i-1;$j>=$n;$j--)
        printf($j);

    printf("<br>");
}

//Se toma como inicio $n-1 porque ya la parte de arriba construye la parte
//intermedia  del rombo (entonces se necesita 1 menos)

for($i=$n-1;$i>=0;$i--) {
    /* print blank spaces */
    for($j=0;$j<=$n-$i;$j++)
        printf(" ");

    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++)
        printf($j);

    for($j=$i-1;$j>=0;$j--)
        printf($j);

    printf("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Si no me di cuenta jeje, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Necesito ayuda con la actividad

Se trata de visualizar un rombo con asteriscos (*) en una matriz de 7 filas x 7 columnas.
Visualizar la matriz por pantalla en formato de tabla html.
Nota:” Solo se rellena el exterior del rombo. Y para el relleno de la matriz hay que usar bucles,
no asignar directamente los caracteres a una posición del array ‘a mano’ ”.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, ni tampoco es una pregunta (ya que debes demostrar lo que intentaste). Si tienes una pregunta en específico que hacer, [formúlala](/questions/ask), leyendo [ask]. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.